# Get gridview selection in modal

Tags: php, jquery, gridview, yii

I've been using `$.fn.yiiGridView.getSelection(<id>)` to get the value of my gridview and it works. But when i try to use this to get the value selected in gridview in modal, it doesn't work. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Please share your code (the code for the modal). Do you use bootstrap modal?

Comment: is the content of the modal dynamically loaded?

Comment: the content is dynamically loaded via render partial

Comment: I am using bootstrap modal